# How to create a dictionary whose values are lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I read a code in a book 'Think Python'. This code gets stuck at the `inverse[val].[key]` with an error:

> 'str' object has no attribute 'append''

Which makes sense as `inverse[val]` contains a string object.
Here d is the input dictionary.

```
def invert_dict(d):
    inverse = dict()
    for key in d:
        val = d[key]
        if val not in inverse:
            inverse[val] = [key]
        else:
            inverse[val].append(key)
    return inverse
```

The input dictionary is `{'a': 1, 'p': 1, 'r': 2, 't': 1, 'o': 1}`

The expected output is `{1: ['a', 'p', 't', 'o'], 2: ['r']}`

How do I implement this, by modifying the given block of code?

Comment: Share what problem are you getting with the above code.

Comment: fix your indentation level, that will solve your problem

Comment: Did an answer below help? If so feel free to accept one (green tick on left), or you can ask for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to create a dictionary of lists. Then append to dictionary values while iterating your input dictionary.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d_in = {'a': 1, 'p': 1, 'r': 2, 't': 1, 'o': 1}

d_out = defaultdict(list)

for k, v in d_in.items():
    d_out[v].append(k)

print(d_out)

defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {1: ['a', 'p', 't', 'o'], 2: ['r']})
```

---

Your code can be improved by iterating keys and values simultaneously via `dict.items`, instead of iterating keys and manually extracting the value. In addition, your indentation is incorrect. After resolving these issues:

```
def invert_dict(d):
    inverse = dict()
    for key, val in d.items():
        if val not in inverse:
            inverse[val] = [key]
        else:
            inverse[val].append(key)
    return inverse
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
def invert_dict(data):
    inverse = {}
    for key, value in data.items():
        if value not in inverse:
            inverse[value] = [key]
        else:
            inverse[value].append(key)
    return inverse
```

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner using [reduce](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce):

```
inverted_dict = reduce((lambda inverted_dict, key: inverted_dict.setdefault(dd[key], []).append(key) or inverted_dict), d, {})
```

Output:

```
{1: ['t', 'o', 'p', 'a'], 2: ['r']}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also follow a different approach in which you take all values from your dictionary and match each value with the keys that have this value in the initial dictionary:

```
def invert_dict(d):
    values = set(d.values())
    inverse = dict((v,[k for k in d.keys() if d[k]==v]) for v in values)
    return inverse


inv = invert_dict({'a': 1, 'p': 1, 'r': 2, 't': 1, 'o': 1})
print(inv)
```

Output:

```
{1: ['a', 'p', 't', 'o'], 2: ['r']}
```